# Variable of a dataframe as the argument of a function

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I simplify my question with this example:
to write a function like

```
calculate = function(var1){
  mean(dataframe$var1)
}
```

but it is not working for me when I write  calculate(Age) or  calculate(speed).
I know how to solve the problem in another way, but I would like to use the **$** symbol to invoke the variable.

Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `mean(dataframe[, var1])`?

Comment: var1 must be a character string, not a variable name. This works and uses $ but it is more trouble than it is worth: `mean(eval(parse(text=paste0("iris$", deparse(substitute(var1))))))`.

Answer (score 0):

You could instead change your symbol to a character using `deparse(substitute())` and use `[[` like so:

```r
calculate = function(var1){
    mean(mtcars[[deparse(substitute(var1))]])
}
calculate(mpg)
# [1] 20.09062
mean(mtcars$mpg)
# [1] 20.09062
```

However, it seems to me easier just to go the `tidyverse`/`dplyr` route if what you're after is referring to variables by symbols

Comment: or if your function is simply `mean(mtcars[,var1])` you can call it with `calculate("mpg")`